# 0's after decimal point are absent in postman response

Tags: c#, json, xml, api, postman

0's after decimal point does not show in postman response.But when I run the same url in Chrome, it works. Please review below previews and let me know whats actually going on. :-). Do I need to do any configuration in postman ?

```
 public class Product
{
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

xxx.Models.Product pr = new xxx.Models.Product();
pr.Price = (decimal)dtTable.Rows[i]["Price"];
pr.Qty= (decimal)dtTable.Rows[i]["Quantity"];
product.Add(pr);
```

Take a look at 'Price' and 'Qty' column/field

Postman JSON response

```
 {
"CustomerID": 6136,
"ProductID": 2000000724,
"PartNo": "9012",
"Qty": 4,
"Price": 150.6
}
```

XML Output in Chrome

```
<Product>
<CustomerID>6136</CustomerID>
<ProductID>2000000724</ProductID>
<PartNo>9012</PartNo>
<Qty>4.00</Qty>
<Price>150.60</Price>
</Product>
```

Comment: unless you have a schema validation for the XML output, all values are passed as `string`, in JSON, ther are being passed as `flot` and `4` is `4.00` if you round up to 2 decimal places

Comment: Thank you. :-) I thought something is wrong with Postman